# How to find a fitting function for [n x n] matrix values

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Given 100x100 matrix where each element represents a function value in space, I would like to find parameter values A, B, C, D, E for a function f(x, y) = A + B*x + C*y + D*X^2+E*y^2 that fits the best the given matrix values, where x represents a row number and y represents a column number

To illustrate the aim on a smaller example, let's say we have a 3x3 matrix T:

```
T = [0.1 0.2 0.1; 0.8, 0.6, 0.5; 0.1, 0, 1]
```

in this case f(1,1) = 0.1 and f(3,2)= 0.

Concretely the matrix values for which I would like to find a fitting function (surface) are displayed in the image below:

[image]

I would be very thankful if anyone suggested a way to find the 3D function that fits (best) the given matrix.

## Edit

Is it possible to find a fit directly or is it neccesary (or better) fo first represent the data as matrix [X, Y, f(X,Y)]:

```
vals = []
for(i = 1: 100)
for j = 1 : 100
if(T(i,j) ~= 0)
vals = [vals;i, j, T(i,j)];
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question.. This is an advanced math question.

Comment: I think you meant to say `f(x,y) = A + B*x + C*y + D*x^2 + E*x*y + F*y^2`. That's how multivariate polynomial functions are usually thought of.

Comment: This does not really make sense as you start with A+B, you should remove at least one of them. Furthermore your variables appear to be linear independant so why not try linear regression?

Comment: Thanks @Phonon for reminding me it's time to take a break :)

Comment: can you reduce the number of fit parameters because really what you have is  `f(x,y)=(c1*x+c2*y)^2` since I can refined `f` to be `f-A` since A is not dependent in x,y, and `c1^2=D , c2^2=F, c1*c2=E' etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These guys seemed to have done it in one line:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/134076

```
x = % vector of x values
y = % vector of y values
z = % f(x,y)

V = [1 x y x.^2 x.*y y.^2];
a = V \ z ;
```

From [the help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html;jsessionid=f628af059d317c12624d7f165d14):

- If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a column vector with m elements or a matrix with m rows, then A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B.